# Can a user barge into django server as another user and perform operatn if he changes info in the frontend if we are using session authentication?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

Hey guys I am confused and was thinking about this problem for sometime now, I am storing the current user's username in the session storage, and I have another page in which I use the stored username for an api call, it can be any requests.

Eg. a post can be deleted by its author only, suppose, the url is `api/<slug>/delete` and in the frontend I have enabled the delete button only for the corresponding user, what if he edits the front end page and changes it to his username or what if I use the stored username to check that condition?
And if he sends a delete request successfully from the frontend, does the django server able to determine that the user in the current session is not the real owner and has tweaked it in the frontend?

Ps. This might be a foolish question, but I am a beginner and quite confused.

Thanks.

Comment: A user can not access the session. Session data is stored at the *server* side. The client only has a session-id that he each time passes with the request.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what I am confused about is, can a person perform an operation as another user if he changes the `username` variable to his own username in the front end? or does it only reflect in the frontend?

Comment: but he can't since it that username is stored at the server side, hence they have no control over this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have one more doubt, like is it normal to save username and user id in session storage for some operations?

Comment: Django already does that, that is what the `request.user` is basically doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naturally, we would need some code to answer your question.
Will the following delete some other user's data?
A user passes a username from the client to the server

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(username=username).delete()
```

Will the above delete the user data whose username is what has been passed from the client? Yes.

You need to always verify and validate data and permissions on the server, and also you should consider using CRUD operations on the current authenticated user (since you are working with sessions), so you don't have to send the current user' username from client, if they are logged in, that can be validated with their session.

I'd advise you to read a little more on Authentication, sessions, ect. [authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/)

Also, I see you are using A RESTful API, so I would strongly recommend using [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/)

Comment: Thank you for the response, so you're saying if I check the condition `request.user.username == username` then proceed...if that is the case, even if the username is changed by the other user to match the current user's username, an action won't be taken by the server?? is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, because the current user's username is not as same as the one sent from the client. That's what are sessions and authentication tokens are for. So you don't have to keep doing this manually, consider using Django's decorators: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator  also if you are using DRF, they provide both session and token authentication + permissions.

Comment: My pleasure. Also if you find the answer to your question useful, please mark it. Thank you.